# Data transfer from sql server to oracle using oracle destination

Tags: sql-server, oracle, ssis, etl, attunity

I want to transfer bulk data from SQL Server to Oracle
So I have used OLE DB Source and Oracle destination (with Attunity)
But I am getting below error

[image: Error]

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: I ran with administrator so got below points 1) cannot find or open pdb file 2) binary was not built with debug information 3) symbols loaded (source information stripped)

Answer (score 1):

I always launch Visual Studio "As An Administrator" for SSIS debugging. Complex tasks like this are a bit unstable otherwise.